# How to make two equal columns in a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have following table:
I can't make `To` and `from` columns to be equal - they should be half of row. I tried many different `colspan` cases, but these `tds` are not half of row.

How could I do that?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="5">

      some text
      <br>

    </td>
    <td colspan="6">
      another text
      <br>

    </td>
    <td colspan="6">
      Logo
      <br>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="8">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="position: relative; font-size: 13px;" colspan="12">
      some text
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height:30px;">
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="6">
      <?php echo 'To');?>:</td>
    <td colspan="6">
      <?php echo 'From';?>:</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "half of row"? half of which row, browser, mobile, ipad, mac...

Comment: can you add a new table for `from` and `to` section? like this http://jsfiddle.net/dnjwa7hj/1/

Comment: Tables are for tabular data - not layout (unless doing an html email template - in which case I wouldn't be using colspans but nested tables)

Comment: Also each row you have (`tr`) must have the same number of columns (`td`) in it.  In your bit of code you have 17 columns in the 1st row, 8 in the 2nd, 12 in the 3rd and 1 in the 4th.  They all should be equal.   [Have a look at these examples to better understand colspan and rowspan](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/td)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to understand the **colspan** property. colspan is used to manage the span of child col with respect to parent. This means if first  has three  and next  has ONE , it means it needs colspan TWO to get in line with parent. You can find this by border='1' property to table

See here

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>

      some text
      <br>

    </td>
    <td >
      another text
      <br>

    </td>
    <td>
      Logo
      <br>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="position: relative; font-size: 13px;" colspan="3">
      some text
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="height:30px;">
    <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo 'To');?>:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <?php echo 'From';?>:</td>
  </tr>
```

Above you cans see my max colspan is THREE since the first  has three rows

Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/anandgh/y1gsqeq6/

Comment: I have ` <td colspan="5">`, ` <td colspan="6">`, ` <td colspan="6">`  in the three columns in first row. I saw jsfiddle, but I couldn't do it in my case to work.

Comment: Why do you need <td colspan="5">, <td colspan="6">, <td colspan="6">? Do you have TR which has 17 <TD>? This is what I said in my answer. Colspan manages the span for missing col. Simply remove them like I did in my Answer

Comment: I need them because text is wrapped on new lines and it's not displayed properly. Td-s are small and can't contain text and it enteres new lines..

Comment: This is surely not the correct way to do that. You should manage the width of table and col in order to get text inside TD in proper way. Still I could do some workaround. Check it out http://jsfiddle.net/anandgh/essp9jj8/

Comment: It's not working in my file. Would you like to show it to you?

Comment: Crate fiddle and paste it here